# Working with HTML and images on Google App Engine

Tags: java, html, image, google-app-engine

I am a bit confused about how to deal with html and images on Google App Engine:

I am displaying a simple website on my naked domain (`example.com`), which is hosted on my Google App Engine directly in the `war` directory. This is working fine.

I have also built an API which I host on Google App Engine, and is available on `example.com/api/v1/`. Now, I am building a functionality in which a new user is being created and a registration confirmation mail is sent to the new user.

This email is a plain HTML page, which I load from `war/WEB-INF/mail/register.html`, because I do not seem to be able to get it from the `war` directory. In this HTML I just refer to an image with `<img src="images/image.png" />`, assuming GAE will search for it in `/war/WEB-INF/mail/images/image.png`, but this is not working. The image is never found.

I also looked at `<static-files>`, which needs to be placed in the `app engine-web.xml`, but I am a bit confused which home directory is used in this.

**My question is:** Can anyone explain how App Engine handles html and images in the `war` and `WEB-INF` directories?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Note: My homepage is just working fine, so these images and css files work without any editing in the `appengine-web.xml`.
Note: I am using Java.

Comment: If this html is within an email, the image paths need to be the full url and are not relative to the html file.  <img src="http://example.com/images/image.png"/>  (The comment text is removing the "http://" in the image url).  Also, images cannot be referenced from the outside if it is under the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Thank you @JeffDeskins, I have used your comment to solve my problem!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I created an answer with the same info - but shows better.

Answer (score 0):

If this html is for an email, the image paths need to be the full url and not relative to the html file.  For example, use:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/image.png"/>
```

Also, images cannot be served if they are under the WEB-INF directory.  Create a static directory to serve the images from.